# JPA Specification predicate with CriteriaQuery.any condition

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm having a ClientTask object which contains list of amployee assigned to this task.

```
public class ClientTask {
    @OneToMany(.....)
    private List<EmployeeBean> assignedTo;
}
```

This onetomany relation is mapped through table CLIENTTASKARTICLE

I'm having required where I need to search all tasks assigned to a given employee.
For that I've written Specification predicate as given below.

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Root<EmployeeBean> from = criteria.from(EmployeeBean.class);
Path<Object> path = from.get("id");
final Subquery<Integer> personQuery = criteria.subquery(Integer.class);
final Root<ClientTaskBean> person = personQuery.from(ClientTaskBean.class);
final Join<ClientTaskBean, EmployeeBean> notes = person.join("assignedTo");
personQuery.select(notes.<Integer> get("id"));
predicates.add(builder.equal(builder.any(personQuery), employeeBean.getId()));
return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
```

This is resulting in query:

select clienttask0_.id as id1_2_, clienttask0_.description as descript2_2_, clienttask0_.name as name3_2_, clienttask0_.status as status4_2_, clienttask0_.taskAssignment as taskAssi5_2_, clienttask0_.taskTime as taskTime6_2_ from CLIENTTASK clienttask0_ cross join EMPLOYEE employeebe1_ where
any (select employeebe4_.id from CLIENTTASK clienttask2_ inner join CLIENTTASKARTICLE assignedto3_ on clienttask2_.id=assignedto3_.taskid inner join EMPLOYEE employeebe4_ on assignedto3_.assignedTo=employeebe4_.id)=1

So in the query generated, where clause is wrong. Where clause is in format
"where any(.....subquery....)=1"
If i change above query to
"where 1=any(.....subquery....)", it will work as expected.

I'm forced to use specification provider because there can be some more where clase which will be decided at runtime.
How to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
...builder.equal(builder.literal(employeeBean.getId()), builder.any(personQuery))...;
```